# HTTPS on aws ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, https, ubuntu-16.04

I installed AWS `Ubuntu 16.04` instance, and I install `nginx`, `php7`, `mysql` on this server, and I allocate IP address and associate it to this server, and I add port :`443` and port :`80` on security group.

I install Wordpress on this instance.

I have domain in namecheap so I create name server entry in route53 in aws and I update it on namecheape.com, now my example.com is working perfectly, I maneged to redirect `www.example.com` to `example.com`. But I couldn't do `http://` to `https://`, I search on google but no luck, I don't know where to start and what to do.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect from http to https, there are a number of ways. One way is to change the nginx configuration

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

The second listen is for ipv6.
You can checkout the serverfault answer here: https://serverfault.com/questions/67316/in-nginx-how-can-i-rewrite-all-http-requests-to-https-while-maintaining-sub-dom